# Area under a curve using the rectangle method

Tags: calculus, summation, riemann-sum

Take $$x_k$$ as the left endpoint of each subinterval to find the area under the curve y = f(x) above the specified interval.
f(x) = 9 − x^2; [0, 3]

What I've done so far is to consider $$\Delta x = \frac{3}{n}$$ and $$x_k=0+(k-1) \cdot \frac{3}{n}$$
My question arises when I'm going to develop the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n (9 − ((k-1) \cdot \frac{3}{n})^2) \frac{3}{ n}$$

I know what to do to complete the problem. Could someone help me?

Comment: You could expand the expression encompassed by the $\sum$ until the sum will be of individual terms (constants, $n$'s and $k$'s). Then use the properties of the $\sum$ to simplify.

Comment: Your $k-1$ should simply be $k$.